# Publishing Infopath 2010 to SharePoint 2010 form library I get error: Cannot update library or list

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath

I have SharePoint 2010 and I have a form library I want to publish my Infopath form to the form library I get error bellow:

```
Cannot update library or list
```

can anyone know how to solve this issue.